# DFS Recursion, why save results instead of running it again

Tags: python, algorithm, implementation

I was doing this leetcode question https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-cameras/.

Here is the solution that passes:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def minCameraCover(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        # children are covered and can cover you, you don't cover parent (parent's parent must place a cam) - 0
        # children are covered and don't cover you, you don't cover parent (parent must place a cam) - 1
        # children are not covered and don't cover you, you cover parent (you place a cam at your loc) - 2
        ans = 0
        if root and not root.left and not root.right:
            return 1
        def dfs(curr):
            nonlocal ans
            if not curr:
                return 0
            if not curr.left and not curr.right:
                return 1
            l = dfs(curr.left)
            r = dfs(curr.right)
            if l == 1 or r == 1:
                ans += 1
                return 2
            if l == 2 or r == 2:
                return 0
            return 1
        
        if dfs(root) == 1:
            ans+=1
        return ans
```

but this doesn't pass:

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def minCameraCover(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        # children are covered and can cover you, you don't cover parent (parent's parent must place a cam) - 0
        # children are covered and don't cover you, you don't cover parent (parent must place a cam) - 1
        # children are not covered and don't cover you, you cover parent (you place a cam at your loc) - 2
        ans = 0
        if root and not root.left and not root.right:
            return 1
        def dfs(curr):
            nonlocal ans
            if not curr:
                return 0
            if not curr.left and not curr.right:
                return 1
            if dfs(curr.left) == 1 or dfs(curr.right) == 1:
                ans += 1
                return 2
            if dfs(curr.left) == 2 or dfs(curr.right) == 2:
                return 0
            return 1
        
        if dfs(root) == 1:
            ans+=1
        return ans
```

Why does it work only if you save the `dfs(curr.left)` and `dfs(curr.right)` in `l` and `r` respectively?

When I googled it was some issue with the recursion changing the result but I don't understand this and don't think the result should change.

Comment: The second code calls `dfs(curr.left)` and `dfs(curr.right)` a *second* time when the condition `dfs(curr.left) == 1 or dfs(curr.right) == 1` is not true. This can cause the value of `ans` to be changed incorrectly compared to the first code where they are called only once.

Comment: The moral of the story is don't modify nonlocal/global variables in recursive functions...

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, `ans` is a nonlocal variable that accumulates the result. If you make extra calls to the recursive function `dfs`, the `ans += 1` line can be executed more than it would be if `dfs` was called once for each subtree.

I suggest adding some logging at critical points in the function, including the line mentioned above, to help understand what's going on.

You could memoize the calls with `functools.cache` to avoid repeated work, but it's better to just use the variables in the top solution (although PEP-8 discourages using `l` as a variable name, because it looks too much like `I` and `1` and is therefore difficult to read).